# Всплывание предупреждения при создании вопроса новичком

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, новички

Много мусорных и однообразных вопросов идет от новичков.

Как правило, они заходят судя что бы задать один единственный вопрос, который либо просьба сделать задачу, либо первая ссылка гугла

После чего их отшивают и они уходят обиженными на киберфорум, где как раз такое прокатывает.

Почему бы для новичков(Рейтинг скажем <100) при нажатии на кнопку "Отправить вопрос" не сделать всплывающее окно с основными правилами по типу:

- Учебные задания должны содержать попытки решения или конкретный вопрос с проблемами
- Если что-то не работает, то вы должны написать желаемое поведение и возникающие ошибки.(Бесят вопросы с листингом кода, где не описано что вообще должно делаться)
- Перед тем, как задавать вопрос проверьте задавался ли он ранее или нет ли на него ответа в виде первой ссылке в гугле(Скажем, вопрос "Как объявить переменную в Си?"-это бесполезный вопрос и ответом на него является 1-ая ссылка в гугле)
- Если вам нужна литература для развития, то перечень книг хранится в этих общих вопросах.
- В вопросах должна быть конкретика того, что именно не получается сделать(Бесят вопросы, где нагло вставляют ТЗ и просят решить за них).

Имхо, это уберет бесконечный поток однообразного мусора на главной, который тут же минусуется и закрывается, а пользователи-однодневки сгорают и убегают на другие ресурсы(Киберфорум)

Например, на хабре что бы сделать первую публикацию нужно чуть ли не тест пройти на то, что ты ознакомился с правилами и все четко понял.

Как вариант, можно сделать тоже самое, так многие не любят читать:

1. Т.е перед публикацией первого вопроса, дается тест из 5 вопросов.
2. Каждый вопрос содержит по 4 примера заданных вопросов. Среди них, как вопросы с корректным оформлением, так и вопросы, которые имеют криво оформление, либо подлежат удалению.
3. Новому юзеру необходимо выбрать те вопросы, которые заданы корректно
       или наоборот некорректно.

Все, кол-во мусора снижается на много %.

Например, если бы был бы тест, то этот наглый пользователь уже бы забил и не стал бы задавать такой вопрос:

> [image: наглый вопрос]

Позаимствовал [отсюда](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8288/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC)

Вот еще [один](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/910388/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-30-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-8) индивид

Как видно, перед/в сессию их популяция увеличивается.

**UPD**

Не понимаю, почему многие думают, что это поспособствует оттоку юзеров.

Если бы там было написано:

> Ты дурак, прочитай правила!

то обида была бы обоснованной, а если бы там была такая формулировка

> Этот сайт содержит в себя опыт русского комьюнити и поэтому мы боремся
>   за качество вопросов и ответов. Предлагаем вам ознакомится с основными
>   правилами перед тем, как вы внесете свой вклад в развитие данного
>   ресурса

, то у нового юзера сразу возникло бы чувство веры в авторитетность и качество данного ресурса и он с удовольствием прочитает свод правил и предостережений.

**UPD**

А еще перед отправкой вопроса можно проверять есть ли в нем картинка. Если есть, то давать всплывающее предупреждение:

> Если картинка является кодом, то ее необходимо заменить на сам код. Если на картинке ошибка, то ее необходимо перебить.

**UPD**

Как еще 1 из вариантом, можно ввести отстойник для новых пользователей, что бы их темы перед выходом на главную проходили премодерацию и откровенный мусор:

> СРОЧНО РЕШИТЕ ЗА 30 МИНУТ

Не просачивался на главную и не портил репутацию ресурсу

Comment: Киберфорум? Один текст для всех сайтов?

Comment: Я к тому, что часто от новичков приходят задачи "Сделайте мне то-то" и не прикладывают свои попытки. Разумеется, все минусуют это и вопрос удаляется. Если бы при постинге вопросов от новичков, было бы предупреждение дополнительное, то таких бы вопросов меньше создавалось.

Comment: @iluxa1810, сомнительно

Comment: @Grundy Почему?

Comment: @iluxa1810, потому что просто предупреждения еще никого не останавливали.

Comment: @Grundy, может быть всех и не остановят, НО какой-то % сразу отпадет.

Comment: @iluxa1810, вряд ли.

Comment: @Grundy, но для ответов ведь сделано.

Comment: @iluxa1810 вас же отображение справки по форматированию не останавливает от поста вопросов с кривым оформлением? и от поста вопросов с кодом-картинкой. И от поста дубликатов. И от поста сразу нескольких вопросов в одном. И даже от КАПСА В ЗАГОЛОВКАХ. Почему это остановит каких-то абстрактных новичков? :)

Comment: @PashaPash это другое:)

Comment: @iluxa1810 с точки зрения отвечающего по метке C# - это то же самое :)

Comment: Про очередь проверок "триаж" не забыли? На en so [включена](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage), у нас - нет, но можно обсудить вопрос её включения

Comment: Ну и уходят эти однодневки и что из этого. Как пришли так и ушли. Гарантий нет, что данный контингент будет далее на ресурсе находится и тем более, будет вносить хоть малейшую пользу, окромя еще с десятка таких "обалденных" вопросов. SO и так популярный ресурс у многих людей и не думаю что в ближайшие годы он просядет в популярности, скорее наоборот. Хотя мусора конечно тонна летит, особенно во время сессий. Проблему вы серьезную подняли, ее надо пообсуждать, может найдем какое-то решение

Comment: @iluxa1810, если бы мне, когда я решил задать первый вопрос, выдали такую страничку, я без долгих раздумий послал бы такой сайт по всем известным адресам

Comment: @avp . Не знаю, что такого критичного в этой страничке. Как будто лучше задать кривой вопрос, получить кучу дизлайков и закрытый вопрос, потом разочароваться в сообществе и так же ливануть.

Comment: @avp ну и вообще если бы там было написано "ты дурак, прочитай правила!", то обида была бы обоснованной, а если бы там была такая формулировка "Этот сайт содержит в себя опыт русского комьюнити и поэтому мы боремся за качество вопросов и ответов. Предлагаем вам ознакомится с основными правилами перед тем, как вы внесете свой вклад в развитие данного ресурса", то у нового юзера сразу возникла вера в престижность данного ресурса и он с удовольствием прочитает правила.

Comment: [Вот очередной яркий пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/910559/262779) - *Решите за меня на языке C++* - круто!!! :)

Comment: @iluxa1810, конечно все люди разные, но я не люблю занудных хомячков (а именно такие ассоциации возникают, когда представляю подобную преамбулу)

Comment: Я бы выдавал окно только в отдельных случаях - например когда в тексте не обнаружено признаков кода, мало букв, и т.п. И в окне давал бы персональную рекомендацию, например: "Добавьте код"

Comment: Непонятно почему следует бояться оттока юзеров. Именно эти юзеры в любом случае уйдут, с ответом или без. Человеку, который не знает, как посчитать объем параллелепипеда, SO без надобности. Проблема как раз противоположная - профессионал, зайдя сюда, и посмотрев на этот праздник слабоумия, не факт, что здесь останется. Общий уровень ресурса складывается из всех вопросов, а таких тут чуть ли не половина.

Comment: Идея премодерации вопросов от новичков на самом деле звучит неплохо. Сейчас существует очередь первых сообщений, но она на практике бесполезна, так как просто перенаправляет в очередь закрытия (в которой проверка длится целую вечность).

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight нужно добавить очередь, в которой можно сразу банить авторов отрицательно воспринятых сообществом вопросов (и ответов заодно). Ещё лучше, чтоб до момента публикации. Тогда заживём!

Comment: @älёxölüt Вы преувеличиваете.

Comment: @älёxölüt Не знаю, на сколько ваш комментарий серьезен, но вы как будто неправильно понимаете суть премодерации. Это не карательная мера, а скорее наоборот. Карательные меры как раз таки уже существуют (и не дают желаемого эффекта). Суть премодерации - просто ограничение видимости, ничего больше.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight ограничение видимости - это всё же не видимость ограничения. Точно такая же карательная мера, вспомните, например, термин "ограничение свободы". Имхо, вопрос с кучей UPD уже начинает становиться более широким, чем заявлен изначально.

Answer (score 6):

Нужно не всплывающее сообщение сделать, а тест на знание правил. Т.е., чтобы на форуме имел право задавать вопросы только тот, кто прошёл тест. Причём тест надо составить так, чтобы ответы на вопросы не были очевидны по принципу "я белый и пушистый". Тогда серьёзность ресурса будет видна сразу и наглядно, а не просто на словах. Если кого это и отпугнёт, то несерьёзных пользователей, которые хотят получить от жизни всё и ничего не отдавая взамен. А нужны ли ресурсу такие люди?

Comment: Вот и я к тому. Зачем тут однодневки... Хочешь задать вопрос? Будь добр пройти мини тест, который состоит из 10 запросов и займет 1 минуту. Серьезные люди смотрят на главную и видя "СРОЧНО РЕШИТЕ ЗА 30 МИНУТ" думают о плохом качестве ресурса. Или ввести какой-нибудь отстойник для новых пользователей, что бы мусор не просачивался на главную.

Answer (score 5):

А предложение интересное, ведь (по крайней мере для незарегистрированных пользоваьелей) при попытки написать ответ предупреждение есть, а вот для вопросов почему-то нет - только справка по маркдауну вылезает:

[image: скриншот ответа]

[image: скриншот вопроса]

Answer (score 4):

1. Много мусора. Да.
2. Предложенное решение не поможет. Как часто вы сами читаете правила? Как часто вы читаете соглашение пользователя или любой другой текст в приложениях? Да даже проще, как часто вы читаете полотна текста/большие диалоги в играх? То-то и оно.

Такое решение либо вообще не поможет, либо даже оттолкнёт новичка от пользования сайтом, если мы будем форсить эти окна.

**Ну и главное:** если это и возможно было бы сделать, то проталкивать инициативу подобную нужно через MSE.

Comment: "Да даже проще, как часто вы читаете полотна текста/большие диалоги в играх" Если они интересны, то всегда=)

Comment: Речь идет не все полотно с правилами ему кидать, а наиболее частонарушаемые - это как раз вопросы по типу "Почему не работает?", где кидается код и не описывается , то как это должно работать.

Comment: @iluxa1810 тут важен процент. Я как разработчик игр могу сказать, что нынешние игроки в большинстве своём даже туториал скипают (или не читают там текст), а потом плачутся, что ничего не понимают в игре.

Comment: @iluxa1810 не знаю, не знаю. Мне кажется, что новички всё так же будут игнорировать такие подсказки.

Comment: На Хабре вообще перед тем, как первый пост сделать нужно чуть ли не тест пройти=)

Comment: @iluxa1810 давно? Когда регался много лет назад, такого не было.

Comment: В году эдак 2013 что-то такое видел перед первой публикацией.

Comment: Под постом я понимал, публикацию своего материала.

Comment: @Suvitruf, тогда почему для ответов это сделано?

Comment: @Qwertiy вероятно, т.к. с ответами дела обстоят сложнее. В вопросе то очевидно, что нужно вопрос задавать. А в ответах многие часто не ответ пишут, а свой вопрос задают или пишут что-то типо "спасибо".

Answer (score 3):

При задании вопроса уже есть подобный блок, хоть и не всплывающий поперёк экрана, а расположенный в правой части страницы:

> [image: Как задавать вопросы]

При использовании адаптивного дизайна на моём Android телефоне баннер выглядит более очевидным:

> [image: Android]

Вполне допускаю, что более навязчивое сообщение, к тому же блокирующее возможность начать писать вопрос ещё больше будет способствовать оттоку новых участников на другие ресурсы. Всё-таки SO хорош тем, что практически любой участник может исправить практически любое сообщение (чего нельзя сказать о большинстве форумов), а значит, даже плохо сформулированный или плохо оформленный вопрос можно попробовать привести к приемлемому виду. Ну, а если нет, что же, функционал закрытия/удаления/голосования против по-прежнему существует на сайте. Дополнительно стоит учесть, что ещё существует так называемый "бан на задание новых вопросов", если предыдущие вопросы участника были закрыты или заминусованы. Лично я не могу сказать, что как-то страдаю от наличия на сайте плохих вопросов от новых участников.

Comment: Ну не знаю. Речь идет только о новичках. Если пользователь реально хочет получить ответ, то он удосужится попытаться привести вопрос в надлежащий вид. Если это шокльник, который спамит свой вопрос на ответах мейл ру, тостер и подобных ресурсах без попыток решить свою проблему, то такого потерять не жалко.

Comment: Хм.. Оно показывается когда курсор в поле заголовка, а когда в теле вопроса - вместо него справка по маркдауну.

Comment: @Qwertiy оно показывается номинально при открытии страницы задания вопроса, а потом да, в зависимости от того, на каком поле фокус.

Comment: @iluxa1810 вы никогда не узнаете, школьник это был со скучной задачей или кто-то с другим более интересным вопросом, если этот вопрос никогда не будет задан, потому что вопрошающий не был достаточно настойчив при соблюдении правил оформления вопроса.

Comment: @älёxölüt, если кто-то хочет влиться в сообщество, то ему не составит это труда.

Comment: @iluxa1810 точно так же и школьник, жаждущий получить ответ на халяву. Если он видит такой шанс - любые препятствия ему будут нипочём.