# Корректно ли убивать наглые вопросы как спам?

Tags: обсуждение, удаление-вопросов, спам

Порой встречаются вопросы не то что плохого качества, а просто бурлящие наглостью, например, [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/910022/176217):

> [image: Срочно]

Такой вопрос быстро закрывается и минусуется, но некоторые умудряются ещё успеть дать ответ (в погоне за репой что ли, не знаю). Скорее всего такой вопрос не требует правки, а должен быть просто удалён. И здесь есть выбор:

- отправить тревогу модератору (нужно что-то написать и долго ждать пока модератор доберётся до неё)
- проголосовать за удаление (для этого нужно сначала закрыть вопрос, иметь  20К репы и дождаться ещё двоих таких солидарных)
- отметить вопрос как спам (вопрос получает дополнительный минус от системы, отметить может любой участник, достаточно, если не ошибаюсь, троих)

Из всех этих пунктов самый последний, имхо, самый действенный, но насколько корректно так поступать, ведь вопрос по сути не является спамом? Может подобная тревога вовсе должна называться как-то иначе, чтобы гасить и спам и вот такие наглые вопросы?

Comment: А вы хотите удалить этот вопрос СРОЧНО ОСТАЛОСЬ 30 МИНУТ? Я думаю, закрыть его вполне достаточно, как за ненадлежащее качество.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko закрытый вопрос тем не менее виден, и под ним можно писать комменты. Иногда это весело, но надо ли оставлять его видимым, если улучшить вопрос нереально?

Comment: Веселенький вопрос...

Comment: @älёxölüt а почему вы считаете, что улучшить его нереально? Меняем название на текст задачки, и вуаля - "Как вычислить объем параллелепипеда зная его стороны?"

Comment: @Kromster редактируйте и голосуйте за восстановление, если считаете иначе.

Comment: @älёxölüt мы же о проблеме в целом. Я такие вопросы обычно минусую, закрываю или флагаю, и редактирую, чтобы они хотя бы прилично выглядели в списке. (а иногда бывало, что после редакции, минус и флаг отзывал)

Comment: @Kromster сферические кони в вакууме и прочие абстракции полезны, но вот есть конкретный случай, почему бы не проявить свои доводы на нём?

Comment: @älёxölüt а зачем? Вы вопрос заметили, волну подняли - это ваш крест теперь :-P

Comment: @Kromster странно всё ещё слышать от автора такого замечательного ответа чуть ниже.

Comment: Я лично не вижу смысла ставить спам. Наглость есть, даже немного хамство, но не спам. Скорее всего отправлю тревогу: "домашние задания допустимы...". Какая разница сколько вопрос провисит  10 минут или 30?

Comment: @älёxölüt Я  пользуюсь тревогой: **необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством**
У данного вопроса серьёзные проблемы с форматированием или содержанием. Поскольку маловероятно, что его удастся улучшить с помощью правок, этот вопрос нужно удалить. Вроде срабатывает быстро. Писать почему, не надо.

Comment: если не ошибаюсь, вопросы с минусом и без ответа с положительным рейтингом удаляются со временем автоматически, поэтому можно просто закрыть и дать шанс ТС исправиться.

Comment: еще https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/910759/ и еще https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/910761  =)

Comment: Если кто-то даёт милостыню наглому попрошайке на улице - это его дело. Если кто-то отвечает на наглые вопросы - это его дело. Более того, если посмотреть сообщения самых высокорейтинговых (уважаемых!) членов стека, у них полно ответов на примитивные вопросы, которые следовало бы закрыть. А-та-та нас всех за это?

Comment: @älёxölüt, ваша ссылка ведет на несуществующий вопрос - это так на всякий случай)) а то думал посмотреть а там ничего нету

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko вам просто [репутации не хватает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) для просмотра удалённых сообщений.

Comment: правда????? я думал что они удалены и все... :)

Answer (score 11):

Как вы верно заметили, вопрос точно не спам, и отмечать его таковым - ошибочно. Если модератор с вами не согласится, что *"надо использовать действенный способ, вместо правильного"*, то вы, вероятно, рискуете получить предупреждение или что похуже.

---

Давайте уточним, чего именно вы хотите достигнуть - иметь возможность экспресс удаления очень плохих вопросов?

Тут нет общего решения, т.к. нет идентичных вопросов. Когда-то подойдет один вариант, когда-то другой:

1. **Отправить тревогу вполне можно** (и м.б. указать свою причину, что вопрос чрезвычайно плох), но наверно излишне, т.к. вопрос (если отложить эмоции) вполне по теме, просто плохо назван, плохо сформулирован, и тривиален по сути для всех кто отучился хотя бы 3 класса.
2. **Проголосовать за удаление и отметить минусом - вполне достаточно.** Вопрос вскоре уйдет с топа и будет закрыт/удален.
3. **Попробовать оперативно спасти** (если вопрос еще не нахватал минусов), т.е. дать нормальное название, изложить задачу, и может быть даже самостоятельно запостить хороший ответ. Вы будете вознаграждены за труды )

Comment: Посмотрел на свою историю флагов по спаму: всего 48, отклонено 1, спорные 3, отозваны 1. Как думаете, все остальные 43 реально были спамом? Ответ - конечно же нет! Поэтому проблема мне видится не в том, что отмечать как спам нельзя, а в том, что описание тревоги должно быть расширено. Даже модераторы это понимают, утверждая соответствующие тревоги.

Comment: 3 вариант однозначно не вариант. Вы бы действительно хотели, чтобы стэк оверфлоу стал местом размещения подобных вопросов?

Comment: @älёxölüt для этого есть тревога "необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством"

Comment: Которая предполагает ожидания реакции модератора или проверяющих из очередей. Т.е. более медленная чем спам.

Comment: @demonplus то что для нас с вами некое знание тривиально, вовсе не значит, что это знание должно быть табуировано для остальных. Из той же серии, мне вот очевидно, как перевести значение из одного мин-макс диапазона в другой, тем не менее вопрос и ответ этот полезен для многих сотен людей.

Comment: @älёxölüt подождем, может кто из мод.состава ответит, какие очереди в каком порядке они разбирают

Comment: @Kromster одно дело, когда просто спрашивают, что-то простое, тогда несложно ответить, а другое, когда человек capslock-ом на тебя орет, что давай, за 10 минут решай его задачу, а то ему недосуг

Comment: @älёxölüt Kromster прав. Вопрос ненадлежащего качества будет удален модератором. Зачем здесь срочность? Почему вы хотите, что бы такие вопросы удалялись как можно быстрее?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko автор хочет СРОЧНО, почему мне нельзя? :) Ну, и я вам уже отвечал в комментариях под вопросом.

Comment: @älёxölüt есть отдельная тревога для модераторов, которая не подразумевает срочность. Удаление спама - срочно. Удаление мусорных вопросов - вообще нет. То, что вы делаете - это просто злоупотребление системой срочности - вы привлекаете модератора просто потому, что вам хочется, вместо того чтобы подождать

Comment: @älёxölüt насчет заапрувленых тревог спама на неспаме - ок, поговорю с другими модераторами, чтобы они перестали так делать. Поймите, тревоги спама на не-спаме - это аналог "**СРОЧНО УДАЛИТЕ**", но в исполнении того, кто поставил тревогу.

Comment: @PashaPash тогда не забудьте ещё и на MSE поговорить, там у меня примерно такая же картина подтверждений :)

Comment: @PashaPash, злоупотребляльщикам можно выписать несколько успокоительных банов :)

Comment: @Grundy сделал сайт чище, путём самосожжения аккаунта, угу.

Comment: @PashaPash насколько я знаю, модератор вообще не нужен для удаления сообщения по тревогам спама. Поэтому замечание об отвлечении модератора от действительно важных дел на спам-не-спам тревогу несколько обескураживает.

Comment: @älёxölüt у модераторов тревоги спама горят ярко-красным, в отдельной секции и значительную часть спама сносят руками именно модераторы.

Comment: @PashaPash горят, пожалуйста, но это же не значит, что они прям среди ночи их с кровати поднимают. Ну, проспал модератор, спам удалился сам собой, можно утром уже другими делами заняться. Очереди там поразгребать... хотя о чём это я, для очередей баракина хватает с головой, можно ещё поспать часок.

Comment: Третий вариант - ужасен, пользователь оставивший такой вопрос не обратит особого внимания на то в какой вид его вопрос переработали. Он просто запомнит что в критической ситуации он запостил свой крик о помощи и получил ответ, в следующий раз в такой же ситуации опять запостит подобный вопрос, а еще и друзьям посоветует. Благими намерениями вымощена дорога в ад :)

Answer (score 2):

> 7. Система автоматически удалит закрытые, разблокированные вопросы с
>      нулевой или отрицательной оценкой, не имеющие ответов с положительным рейтингом или
>      принятых ответов, или голосов для повторного открытия, которые
>      были закрыты по какой-либо причине, кроме "дубликат" девять или более
>      дней назад и не были отредактированы за последние девять дней.
>      (RemoveAbandonedClosed)
> 8. ...
> 9. Система автоматически удалит разблокированные и неотвеченные вопросы с отрицательным рейтингом, которым старше 30 дней.
>      (RemoveDeadQuestions)

[Источник на meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/307712)

[Источник на ru.meta.stackoverflow.com](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2293/)

Достаточно закрыть вопрос и поставить минус. Этим можно дать ТС возможность <strike>исправиться</strike> изменить вопрос для соответствия правилам, а если он не захочет, то система удалит вопрос автоматически спустя определенное время.

Comment: *"Этим можно дать ТС возможность..."* не тот случай, если сделать акцент на упомянутом примере. Просто понимаете, хочется убрать такой вопрос как можно скорее, дабы он даже в поисковой выдаче не попадался. Так-то вопросы от минус 8 и ниже с главной уже пропадают, но видны через поиск по меткам, например.

Comment: @älёxölüt не факт, он может попробовать сам решить задачу, привести свой пример кода, пусть и не работающего, изменить заголовок и т.д. и вопрос будет соответствовать. было бы желание.

Comment: И ник свой тоже поменять, да-да, конечно. Был СРОЧНО, станет ГОТОВ ПОДОЖДАТЬ.

Comment: @älёxölüt тогда уже "ПОПРОБОВАЛ, НЕ ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ, ГОТОВ ПОДОЖДАТЬ "=) А так, было бы желание, горит у человека, пусть остынет. А сжигать вопрос сразу же не совсем правильно, пахнет агрессией, хоть реакция и понятна. Для этого есть автоматическое удаление. Интересно карма ему после такой репы и флагов "спам" позволит задать вопрос на данном аккаунте?

Comment: После утверждения как спам - не думаю, что получится повторить.

Comment: @älёxölüt в данном случае вместо возможного участника мы можем получить еще одного обиженного на ru.so. Здесь многое еще от конкретного ТС как человека зависит, один прочтет справку, другой обидится и уйдет, но при блокировке новых вопросов проблемы будут у обоих.

Comment: Мне считаю, любой адекватный человек поймёт, что вопрос, сформулированный в подобной форме не соответствует нормальному вопросу, где бы он не был задан. Не нужно никакие справки для этого читать.

Answer (score 0):

СПАМ [Вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC) — массовая рассылка корреспонденции (сообщений-вопросов) рекламного или **иного** характера лицам, не выражавшим желания её получать.

Я уже писал https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7398/17974 ответ что такое спам.

Сообщения, которые не несут никакой пользы а лишь "засоряют" эфир - я считаю спамом, тем более, что сейчас появились интересные виды СПАМ,
например *поисковый спам*, когда какую-то тему нужно набрать очки в поисковике/гугле/яндексе, а уже на данную "тему" вас ждет "сюрприз" - рекламка. Но что б "нужные" слова стали "топовыми" в поисковике, нужно что б на топовых сайтах появились соответствующие "волшебные" слова. Например: часть людей (кто-то из нас) прочтя вопрос, решим - так это просто, и полностью или частично будет искать эту фразу в поисковике - что бы сослаться - решение есть - и повысим рейтинг данного словосочетания. А под сочетание слов - поисковик вверху покажет рекламу которую заказали некто заказчики:)

Закрытие. Сообщение будет удалено, только если 6 (шесть) участников поставят тревогу с отметкой спам - тогда сообщение удалится системой быстро, без участия пользователей с повышенными привилегиями.

P.S. Вопрос спорный, я бы в 50% случаев упомянуты вопрос отнёс бы к СПАМу, но если бы увидел голос или комментарий что это спам, то 100% поддержал бы голосом. Подумав что в вопросе задание достаточно вроде "простое", не относится к с++, и достаточно короткое - то я склоняюсь отнести его к СПАМ.

Comment: Так вы спамом назовете все что угодно. Вот мой комментарий *иного характера* и вы ведь заранее не хотели его получить - тоже спам? :-D *"повысим рейтинг данного слово-сочетания. А под сочетание слов - поисковик вверху покажет рекламу которую заказали некто заказчики:)"* вот эта схема и связь мне кажется очень притянута за уши.