# Как правильно задать вопрос, если для полного его понимания нужно выложить кучу кода?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы

Задал ранее вопрос, все расписал полностью, выложил весь код, старался форматировал - ничего кроме троллинга я не получил. Что в этом вопросе не так и как мне получить на него ответ?

Ссылка на вопрос:
[Тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/912180/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B)

Comment: там были какие-то удаленные комментарии? Сейчас просто никаких сообщений под вопросом нет

Comment: @Grundy да, были, замечания о том что это простыня, точнее одеяло кода.

Answer (score 5):

Если для полного понимания вопроса нужна куча кода, то такой вопрос однозначный кандидат на закрытие по причине отсутствия [минимального воспроизводимого примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Мало кому будет интересно разбирать эту кучу кода, т.е. вы просто рискуете, как минимум, остаться без ответа.

Для дополнительного чтения рекомендую ознакомиться со смежным вопросом: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/176217)

Comment: Ну так правильно, я этим и руководствовался, а точнее - 2 пунктом где говорится о том что вопрос должен содержать код который демонстрирует проблему. Если следовать Вашей логике - то вопросы которые не содержат необходимый код - сведутся к постоянному уточнению и переписке в комментариях, что в итоге всё равно приведет к той же куче кода, если не больше.

Comment: Мы уже не позиционируем себя как сайт, где *встречаются* (если, конечно, вопрошающему повезет) профессионалы и на всякий случай сложные вопросы убираем?

Comment: @Антон код должен быть **минимален**. Из вашего кода действительно нельзя больше ни байта убрать чтобы он не потерял смысла проблемы?

Comment: @avp сложность бывает разная. Если она неделима - это один вопрос. Если можно разбить на подзадачи, то скорее всего проблему можно описать компактнее.

Comment: @älёxölüt, я ведь не против, что если человек *может* сделать минимальный пример, то пусть делает (это будет очень хорошо). А если не может? Я думаю, мы не должны отказывать ему (и возможно кому-то, кто с удовольствием возьмется такую задачку порешать).

Comment: @avp по какой причине он может не мочь?

Comment: @älёxölüt, какая разница? Может умом слаб, а может времени нет. Согласитесь, что если бы все были сообразительны и усидчивы, то нас бы тут не было

Comment: @avp а потом появляются [вопросы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8288/176217)

Comment: @älёxölüt то что можно убрать с моего кода - это действительно селекты и прочие неиспользуемые инпуты. С этим согласен, я недосмотрел. Но вот драг энд дроп и всю ту js простыню - сократить никак нельзя так как там расписано получение списка аттачей, запись его в formData и попытка отправки. Я перепишу еще раз свой вопрос, мне не сложно, я просто хочу понять и научиться.

Comment: @älёxölüt, почему бы просто не пройти мимо вопроса, который не нравится? Если он всем не нужен, так через пару часов он уже исчезнет из поля зрения.

Comment: Поправил вопрос, кому интересно. Так лучше?
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/912180/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-php

Comment: @avp мы здесь не для того, чтобы быть безучастными.

Comment: @älёxölüt (¬‿¬ )

Comment: @älёxölüt, иногда лучше ничего не делать. Ломаете ведь изначально  хорошую вещь

Comment: @avp вы сейчас что имеете в виду?

Comment: @älёxölüt, как всегда -- *хватит закрывать вопросы* (кроме абсолютного бреда)

Answer (score 5):

Тут, на самом деле, проблема не в простыне кода, а в том, что задача слишком узкоспециализированная.

Даже если вам дадут ответ, то вряд ли такой вопрос поможет кому-то ещё. Такие вопросы, как минимум, на том же SOen не особо приветствуются.

Ну и, с другой стороны, если бы вы такой вопрос увидели с кучей текста, стали бы в нём разбираться? В этой мешанине js/php/html кода без отступов и форматирования прямиком из начала 2000-х?

Я мельком глядя на код, могу сказать, что там процентов 80 можно выбросить, т.к. они к проблеме отношения не имеют. Все эти десятки `option`'ов, `select`'ы и т.п. По-хорошему вам нужно сделать минимальный пример с проблемой. Достаточно, думаю, формы с одним полем. js `dragover` и т.п. методы тоже лишние. Логов консоли нет. Логов сервера нет.

Comment: Смотрите, может я что не так понимаю. Суть задачи в том чтобы дать возможность юзеру редактировать список аттачей перед отправкой, и чтобы был в наличии драг энд дроп. Это, согласитесь каждая вторая форма с аттачами на сайте, то бишь проблема распостраненная. Касательно того почему не смог решить сам - да действительно, как ктьол-то выразился я пока еще слаб умом. Касательно логов с сервера и консоли - так отписано ведь было что с сервера возвращается ошибка 4, а в консоли отправка запроса выдает 200, типа все ок.

Comment: @Антон я вообще не против вопроса в целом, понимаю, что порой новичку сложно его урезать. Просто, лично я, вряд ли бы стал на такой вопрос отвечать, т.к. слишком долго вникать придётся.